# Scrapy - how to increase number of scheduled start_requests?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a spider which crawls multiple websites. I noticed that even if the list of websites has almost 400 items, the `start_requests` method `yields` only 15 or 16 at the beginning of crawling and working on them without scheduling the other 385 website urls.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for d in Domain.objects.all(): 
        self.allowed_domains.append(d.name)
        yield scrapy.Request(d.main_url, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'domain': d, 'depth': 0},priority=3)
```

I can see in debugger that only first 16/15 urls are `yielded` and then, long time, nothing.

I need to make scrapy to schedule all of those urls because I have set a delay for the same domains and this is very inefficient.

How to do that?

Comment: Increasing [CONCURRENT_REQUESTS](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#concurrent-requests) doesn't help?

Comment: @TomášLinhart No, I've set it even to 400 and it didn't help. The problem is that the downloader is probably filled by urls extracted one of start_urls which leads to very slow scraping since there is REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN set to 1.